# Handle wifi hotspot access in iOS apps

Tags: ios, wifi, captivenetwork

My device (ios8) connects to starbucks wifi when I enter, and when I start browse, it throws captive UI asking me to agree & connect. All fine. But I am missing something in my app because of which it is not able to connect to the network, nor it doesn't know how to launch the captive UI. What should I do to fix this? I use Reachability module and I can detect when the network is down but don't know how to trigger authentication page.. Appreciate any help. Thanks!